# CSS floating div falls to bottom of the screen when reducing screen size

Tags: html, css, css-float, floating

I've been taking care of [this website](http://www.efena.net) for friends of mine (but I barely know the original designer) since last week. I've been working on the PHP mainly, but something bothers me:

Basically the main page and the whole design look like:

```
----------------------------------
Banner
----------------------------------
|Nav  |   |Div #1 floats right   |
|     |   |80% width             |
|float|   |                      |
|left |   -----------------------
|     |   |Div #2 floats right   |
| 16% |   |80% width (same as #1)|
-------   |----------------------|
```

When reducing the window size, everything works alright until a certain point where Div#1 and Div#2 migrate to the bottom of the page, giving this arrangement :

```
---------------------------
Banner
---------------------------
|Nav  |   
|     |  
|float|  
|left |  
|     |  
| 16% |  
-------   
    |Div #1 floats right   |
    |80% width             |
    |                      |
     -----------------------
    |Div #2 floats right   |
    |80% width (same as #1)|
    |--------------------- |
```

I dont want this to happen but unfortunately I don't know a lot about CSS. I tried to position the divs absolutely and to write min-widths to prevent the browser from shrinking the page more than necessary.

Is there a cheap way to fix this without rewriting the CSS completely ?

Comment: Can you please accept an answer when you are done, otherwise, people may work on you question without realizing that you have found a solution, thank-you!

Comment: Yes, I found another way to solve my problem and was just thinking about answering my own question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this rules from `.texte` element:

```
min-width: 584px;
padding: 10px;
margin-right: 5px;
```

- `[!]` When you are working with percentage numbers, don't use `padding` and `margin`. Instead set them for inner childs.

Also remove this rules from `#menu` element:

```
min-width: 119px;
```

Comment: Thx I'll try that. The "min-width:" were temporary measures i just added.

Comment: That did it! (now i have to cope with overflow but it shouldn't be a problem). Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

try to add a div under the floating divs. and give it a class name of clear. then in your css document add the following

```
.clear{clear:both}
```

Comment: thanks but I dont really get it to work. How do I position this div to the bottom ?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is most likely the "min-width: 584px;" in the .texte class.

When I use the Ruler from the Web Developer extension, that div drops to the bottom when it gets to 584 pixels wide.

Comment: Thanks for looking at the CSS.

As I wrote I added these "min-width: 584px;" to try to fix the problem. 584px is the minimal "acceptable size". Unfortunately it didn't change nothing.